# How to change password after user login in android ? In shared Preferences?

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences, token, change-password

I use token based authentication in my app. When user logins through Android app the server returns token which needs to be sent with each subsequent request.

I need to store that value on the devices. Since token is a simple string, I thought I'd use SharedPreferences to hold that value.

Two think confuse me on which method save token in sharedpref. and other one is where to receive the token while implementing change password.

- Use Aynch task For network task
- Use Post Method Api

Answer (score 1):

try something like this.. Create a class for saving values

```
 public class SharedPreferenceCustom {
    private String defValue = "";
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public SharedPreferenceCustom(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("app_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void setSharedPref(String inputKey, String inputValue) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(inputKey, String.valueOf(inputValue));
        editor.apply();

    }

    public String getSharedPref(String inputKey) {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(inputKey, defValue);
    }
}
```

and call whenever needed

Call by

```
   SharedPreferenceCustom sp = new SharedPreferenceCustom(mContext);
   sp.setSharedPref("KEY", "VALUE");
   // or
   sp.getSharedPref("KEY");
```

Comment: is this complete answer?? Also no need to get `SharedPreferences` every time when you need to set values.(As `SharedPrefernces` returns singleton object).

Comment: OP has asked two confusions, this is solution of only. So your answer is not complete. Please make it complete. Thanks

Comment: this is very basic about shared preferences, i need to know how to save token and use while implementing the change password request. @Sanoop

Comment: Ok, i will make a guess, you need the access token to update the password, upon changing password will it return the new token value? @DevPreetMundhra

Comment: So whats the confusion, you can get the token by *getSharedPref* for calling change password api, and once the response is received, update the new token value with *setSharedPref* with the same *KEY* used for saving the access token for the first time.